# Firebase free plan hosting limits

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

What does "GB stored" & "GB downloaded" mean in the Firebase free plan (spark)? Is this limit per month or not?

From https://firebase.google.com/pricing/:

> - GB stored: 1 GB.
> - GB downloaded: 10 GB.

Comment: Data transfer quota is always per month. Storage quota is always the total you can have at any one time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is a limit of one month.

**GB stored: 1 GB**. - This is how much can be stored on data firebase

**Downloaded: 10 GB** - The amount of data that can be downloaded from the server.

Example: You have stored a picture or other file size of 100 MB. Stored will be filled to 100 MB, and downloaded. the file will be able to download (download on the site is also considered) 100 times.

But the images should be stored in the **"File Storage"**.

**Stored 5 GB**

**Downloaded 30 GB**.

**"Realtime Database"** for storing text data (json)

Comment: What if I delete the data from the database on daily basis? I need a temporary storage only. Is there any bandwidth limit?

Comment: I would love some clarification or any resource on "File Storage". Is that part of your Firebase web hosting space or is it accessed differently? Thanks.